# incrementing last id from sql to vb10

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

i want to increment a no. from sql it should be like this 13-001 but it makes 13-1 here's my code

```
Private Sub getLastID()

    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Dim Cmd As New SqlCommand
    con.Open()
    With Cmd
        .Connection = con
        .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbl_student ORDER BY Student_no DESC"
    End With
    dr = Cmd.ExecuteReader

    If dr.Read Then
        lblStudentNo.Text = Val(dr.Item(0)) + 1
    End If

    con.Close()
End Sub
```

what should i do? thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PadLeft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padleft%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) method.

Try this:

```
 lblStudentNo.Text = Val(dr.Item(0)) & "-" & "1".PadLeft(3, "0")
```

Comment: do you have id data with value greater than 999?

Comment: sir the output is this 13100. i want output like this 13-001 then it is incrementing by 1 example 13-001 becomes 13-002 thanks

Comment: sorry, just change `PadRight` to `PadLeft`

Comment: sir it doesnt read the last value and it doesnt incrementing by 1